# timer on counting the total time execution on a program for c++?

Tags: c++, timer

So I have this following simple program that I would like to have a timer imprinted in the program to count the exact time it takes for the program to execute on the number of n times.

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
for (int j=1; j>=i; j++){
    cout << "perfecto" << endl;
```

I was thinking of using the ctime library to help me out with the timer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


time_t time_1;
time_t time_2;
time ( &time_1);

int main(){
int n=5;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<=i; j++){
        cout << 'test';
}
}
}

time (&time_2 );

cout<<'time taken for the algorithm :'<<time_2 - time_1 << seconds <<endl;
```

Will this work somehow because when I ran this it shows me an error just like this.
[image]

Is there any other way to do it and is it possible to add a timer when starting the program?

Comment: It looks like your last two lines are outside of `main`, as is `time(&time_1);`.

Comment: You should learn to properly indent your code. I think that would help with the problem with the placement of { and } as you can visually see your scope with proper indentation

Comment: Also note that `time` is probably in seconds. If your program runs quickly enough you'll get a time of zero. You may need to use a higher precision timer such as the ones available in [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Answer (score 3):

Statements to be executed have to be inside function bodies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){ // move here

time_t time_1;
time_t time_2;
time ( &time_1);

// move this above
//int main(){
int n=5;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<=i; j++){
        cout << 'test';
}
}
// move this below
//}

time (&time_2 );

cout<<'time taken for the algorithm :'<<time_2 - time_1 << seconds <<endl;

} // move here
```

Also there are some more errors:

- Undeclared `j` and `seconds` are used.
- Multi-character character literals are used where I think string literals should be used.

Do you mean this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    time_t time_1;
    time_t time_2;
    time ( &time_1);

    int n=5;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<=i; j++){
            cout << "test";
        }
    }

    time (&time_2 );

    cout<<"time taken for the algorithm :"<<time_2 - time_1 << "seconds" <<endl;

}
```